# Gnuplot - plot for - first row as labels

Tags: gnuplot

Version of gnuplot:5.4

I have dataset in format:

```
Label1 Label2 Label3
1 2 3 
2 5 6
```

I want to use plot for command, because number of columns isnt static and I want to use first row of dataset as labels.

When i use:
`plot for [i=2:dataset_columns] 'dataset.dat' using ($1):($i) with lines axes x1y1`

Error:

```
warning: bad data on line 1 of file dataset.dat
Column number or datablock line expected
```

Question:
How to edit my command to get data printed, how to use first row as labels?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gnuplot console check `help plot for`. If you read it to the end you will see:

> If an iteration is to continue until all available data is consumed,
> use the symbol * instead of an integer . This can be used to
> process all columns in a line, all datasets (separated by 2 blank
> lines) in a file, or all files matching a template.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
>   plot for [i=2:*] 'datafile' using 1:i with histogram
>   splot for [i=0:*] 'datafile' index i using 1:2:3 with lines 
>   plot for [i=1:*] file=sprintf("File_%03d.dat",i) file using 2 title file
> ```

**Code:**

```
### plot all columns until last column
reset session

$Data <<EOD
Label1 Label2 Label3
1 2 3 
2 5 6
EOD

plot for [col=2:*] $Data u 1:col w l title columnhead
### end of code
```

**Addition:** (in case you have a datafile named `datafile.dat`)

```
Label1 Label2 Label3
1 2 3 
2 5 6
```

**Code:**

```
### plot all columns until last column
reset session

plot for [col=2:*] 'datafile.dat' u 1:col w l title columnhead
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Still not working and same error,I have file 'dataset.dat' with type of dataset as Ive sent. In script I have command: `plot for [i=2:storage_columns] dataset.dat using ($1):($i) with lines axes x1y1 title columnhead`

Comment: my code is copy&paste code. There should be no error. Then something is special with your file or setup. Are you using Linux? How do you start your script, from gnuplot console?

Comment: try: `plot for [i=2:storage_columns] 'dataset.dat' u 1:i w l title columnhead`

Comment: It runs on RHEL, version of gnuplot:5.4. I have script with all commands and then I run my script with command like `gnuplot -e datasets='dataset.dat dataset2.dat' script.plt` and save output to svg.

Comment: Ok so `plot for [i=2:storage_columns] dataset.dat using ($1):i with lines axes x1y1 title columnhead` is correct, thank you for your help :)

Comment: your suggested edit of my answer will not work in gnuplot 5.2. Maybe they have changed the syntax in 5.4, I don't know and cannot test.

Comment: I tried it in 5.2 on my laptop and `plot for [col=2:*] 'dataset.dat' u ($1):col w l title columnhead` seems to work, can you just try it and edit if its working?